# ggplotly - R, change limit of characters for the trace names in the hover

Tags: r, ggplot2, hover, scatter-plot, plotly

I have the following plot generated with ggplot2:

```
head(tab)
                FC         PVAL                                                              ID
SLC27A5  -1.902958 8.721649e-05                                 fatty acid transporter activity
ABAT      1.614133 1.423834e-04                                           metal cluster binding
PTDSS1   -1.129185 1.556689e-04                                            transferase activity
SIGMAR1  -1.226052 1.880870e-04                                                            <NA>
PMVK     -1.244247 3.207809e-04 transferase activity, transferring phosphorus-containing groups
B3GALNT2 -1.057636 4.188294e-04                                            transferase activity

p <- ggplot(data = tab, aes(x = FC, y = -log(PVAL), colour = ID, text = paste('gene: ', rownames(tab)))) + geom_point(alpha = 0.5) + theme_classic() + coord_cartesian(xlim = xlim) + theme(legend.position="none")
ggplotly(p)
```

[see plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rphsI.png)
so that points are coloured by `id` (character strings with a length usually > 15 letters). Although the plot is alright, the labels of the hover corresponding to `id` (the colouring) are cut and I see only a fraction of the name and dots (for example *transferase...* instead of *transferase activity*). Do you know how to allow for larger (whole) names?

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example? you can increase the text size using `+ theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"))`

Comment: I don't mean the text size, but the length of the shown text

Comment: you code works very well (id not cut off) for me regardless of the length of the text

Comment: yes, but I need to allow for longer strings of IDs at the plotly plot